# Is it safe to store data locally on a phone?

Tags: ios, swift, security, firebase-realtime-database, jailbreak

In my application I update the user data when the user logs out or closes the application.
The problem is that when he closes the application, the OS stops all the processes of the application, so I can't do my writing on Firebase.
What I want to do instead is save this data locally on the device and when the user logs back in, do the update.
I was going to save them via User Defaults but I thought that if the user had a jaibreak phone, they could theoretically access that memory area and therefore change values.

Am I getting the wrong idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, normally the sandbox of your app is protected but a super-user can access to it and read data. In this case, one solution is to prevent app-launching on rooted or jailbroken phone. There are some libs like this [one](https://github.com/securing/IOSSecuritySuite) to detect jailbroken phone. Some times it better to stop the app and launch a pop-up explaining why the app can't run on this phone because of cybersec rule.

But doing that keep in mind you will lost some users.

Comment: If the data is backed up, a user can modify the backup and then restore it, entirely without a jailbreak. If data integrity is imperative, server-side is the only option.

Comment: Ok so this means that all locally stored data is likely to be corrupted

Answer (score 1):

To your primary issue, writing data when the user leaves the app, this has several well-supported solutions. This is a canonical example of what `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` is for. Whenever you begin a Firebase update, call `beginBackgroundTask`, and whenever you finish the update, call `endBackgroundTask`. That will tell the OS that you're currently performing an action that could benefit from a little more time before being terminated. You should expect something on the order of 30 seconds to a minute. (It used to be more like 3 minutes, but it's been tightened in newer OS versions.) That should be plenty of time for most updates.

If you are using URLSession directly, you can also make use of background tasks. See [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background) for details. This can be used to send data, not just transfer files. It has the major advantage of queuing operations when currently offline, and the OS will perform the transfer when possible, even if your app is no longer running. That said, this is all more complex to implement, and likely overkill for this kind of problem.

That said, if you're storing the access token anywhere in your program (including in memory), a user who reverse engineers your app can always connect to Firebase directly and send anything they want. Whether you store it in UserDefaults, in a file, or just in memory doesn't really change that. Also, last I checked, Firebase doesn't support certificate pinning if you're using their SDK, so a user can just rewrite your packets using a proxy anyway without even jailbreaking the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be better to store user's data in cloud.

Comment: Firebase is a cloud storage system. The problem the question is about how to deal with situation when there was not enough time to write the data bac to Firebase before the user closes the app.